# Conditional SQL on Volume of Records

Tags: sql-server

I need to set up an "alert" (will send an email) if the insertion of records in, say, 1 hour, exceeds, say, 10 records.
I'm thinking about doing this in an INSERT trigger, but I'm not clear on what the best way to check that condition (or the syntax for it) is.

Thanks

Comment: You mean the trigger or sending email? And the table, does it have a creation time?

Comment: The insert trigger would need to add information to an auditing table -- then it could send an email or another process could look at that table to send the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have created time on your table

```
Create Trigger trig_CheckRecordCount
ON TableName
For Insert 
as
Begin

    IF( (select COUNT(*)
    from TableName
    where CreatedOn >
         (
    Select DATEADD(HOUR,-1, CreatedOn)
    from inserted))>10)
    begin
        //call a stored procedure to send email
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a trigger and an audit table is the best way to do this.  What I would do is the following:

Add a column (of type datetime) to your table called CreateDT

You can add a default value of GETDATE() to the column.

Then in an external process you can do a select like the following

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE CreateDT > dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,datediff(hour,-1,getdate())),0)
   and CreateDT  < dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,0,@datetime),0)
```

This will check the prior hour counts.

To check the last 24 hours counts you could get a list like this

```
SELECT HOUR(CreateDT), COUNT(*)
FROM (
       SELECT CreateDt
       FROM TABLE
       WHERE CreateDT > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
     ) T
GROUP BY HOUR(CreateDT)
```

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - no worries, it was just a formatting fix... the same one you made